ggplot: Using commas in data labels with no blank space
I am working on a chart in ggplot. Some of my numbers are large (1000+) so I want to use commas as a thousands separator to make numbers easier to read. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do that without R adding extra space to the left of the number in the data label box when the number has fewer digits than the max number. Below is the code I tried, and the picture to demonstrate the problem. Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

df <- data.frame( Year = c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2023), 
                  Var1 = c(1509.89, 21698, 140.98, 500), 
                  Var2 = c(2, 3000.9, 410.4, 5), 
                  Var3 = c(198.51, 2430.49, 421, 4853) ) 

spline_Var1 <- as.data.frame(spline(df$Year, df$Var1))
spline_Var2 <- as.data.frame(spline(df$Year, df$Var2))
spline_Var3 <- as.data.frame(spline(df$Year, df$Var3))

splines <- bind_rows(
  list(Var1 = spline_Var1, 
       Var2 = spline_Var2, 
       Var3 = spline_Var3),
  .id = "var"
)

df <- df |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(Var1, Var2, Var3), names_to = "var", values_to = "value"
  )


ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = var)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = var), data = splines) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = Year, y = value, 
                       label = format(round(value, digits = 0),big.mark=",",scientific=FALSE)), 
                   max.overlaps = Inf)




One option would be to use scales::comma:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(scales)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = var)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = var), data = splines) +
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(
      x = Year, y = value,
      label = scales::comma(value, accuracy = 1)
    ),
    max.overlaps = Inf
  )



This works perfectly! Thank you!
